# Excel COUNTIFS based on greater than or equal to past date

Tags: excel-formula, countif

I'm trying to count ratings based on user feedback from a specific time period. I need to get totals from the past week/month/year, on how people are rating our service. So, I need to know the number of **5**'s people have given us since "last week".

Currently my cell uses this function:

> =COUNTIFS(StarTable[Rating],G2,StarTable[Date],">="&N2)

*G2 being the specific number rating, and N2 being =TODAY()-7*

If I remove the **">="&** portion, I'll get a return of the number of **5**'s we received on N2's date. Adding the operator returns a 0.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the dates in StarTable[Dates] are correctly formatted as type 'Date'. It sounds like yours are being interpreted as strings. So Excel is able to compare, for example "04/03/2019" to TODAY()-7 and find they match, but it is unable to do anything sensible with "04/03/2019" >= TODAY()-7